# using javascript to grab javascript/cdata in html

Tags: javascript, cdata

what is the best way to grab the `memberId` from this data and show it in an `alert()` dialog?

I would like to make this a bookmarlet something like this:

```
javascript:alert("member ID is\n"+document.getElementsByName("memberid")[0].value);
```

(This doesnt work; it's just an example.)

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
  //<![CDATA[
    var _SKYAUTH = {
      loginUrl:'',
      memberNick:'',
      memberId:'233669',
      profileUrl:'',
      photoUrl:''
    };
  //]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want to make a bookmarlet

You should be able to catch the variable using

```
alert(_SKYAUTH.memberId);
```